# Check Checkboxes from an array of objects on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i have a model like this

```
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this

    self.Choices            =   ko.observableArray([])
    self.AcceptedChoices    =   ko.observableArray([])

    self.LoadData   =   function(){
        self.ViewAnswered()
    }   

    self.ViewAnswered = function(){
        var url =   'QuestionsApi/ViewAnswered'
        var type    =   'GET'
        ajax(url , null , self.OnViewAnsweredComplete, type )                   
    }
    self.OnViewAnsweredComplete = function(data){
        var currentAnswer = data.Answer

        self.Choices(currentAnswer.Choices)
        self.AcceptedChoices(currentAnswer.AcceptedChoices)
    }       

    self.LoadData()         
}
```

Here is my object. I have removed extra things

```
{
    "AcceptedChoices": [94, 95],
    "Choices": [{
        "ChoiceId": 93,
        "ChoiceText": "Never"
    }, {
        "ChoiceId": 94,
        "ChoiceText": "Sometimes"
    }, {
        "ChoiceId": 95,
        "ChoiceText": "Always"
    }]
}
```

And here is binding

```
<u data-bind="foreach:Choices">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" data-bind="value:ChoiceId,checked:$root.AcceptedChoices">
        <span data-bind="text:ChoiceText">Never</span>
    </li>
</u>
```

Now the problem is that checkboxes are not being checked due to the choices being array of objects. How can i resolve this issue? Although the same thing works for radio where there is only one selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind i have found a solution here

[checked binding does not properly compare primatives](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/529)

Also it tells two ways for this. The Solution provided in fiddle is creepy so i will use the one using knockout version 3.0.0.

All i need to do is attach knockout-3.0.0.js instead of any other and then use `checkedValue` instead of `value`.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" 
    data-bind="
            checkedValue:ChoiceId,
            checked:$root.AcceptedChoices"
>
```

And that's done. Hope it helps someone.

EDITS :

I noticed it is not working on the Chrome. So i found an alternative. I created these two functions.

```
self.ConvertToString = function(accepted){
    var AcceptedChoices =   []
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(accepted, function(item) {
        AcceptedChoices.push(item.toString())
    })  
    return  AcceptedChoices
}
self.ConvertToInteger = function(accepted){
    var AcceptedChoices =   []
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(accepted, function(item) {
        AcceptedChoices.push(parseInt(item))
    })  
    return  AcceptedChoices         
}
```

And use them

```
self.AcceptedChoices(self.ConvertToString(currentAnswer.AcceptedChoices))
```

To get the value

```
AcceptedChoices: self.ConvertToInteger(self.AcceptedChoices()),
```

Comment: Yeah, that's why I ended up doing it the way I put in my answer. Good to know it's finally fixed in 3.0!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be checking to see if the Id of a choice is in the AcceptedChoices array. Use the ko.utils array function to help do that:

```
checked: function() { return ko.utils.arrayFirst($root.acceptedChoices(), function(item){
    return item == ChoiceId();
} !== null }
```

You could put this into a function on your root object:

```
self.isChoiceAccepted = function(choiceId){
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst($root.acceptedChoices(), function(item){
        return item == choiceId;
    } !== null
};
```

then call it in your data-bind as:

```
checked: function() { return $root.isChoiceAccepted(ChoiceId()); }
```

This isn't tested, I'm not 100% sure that the arrayFirst method returns null if it doesn't find a matching item in the array, so chack that.